# Why doesn't my dialogue box open up?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm trying to allow the user to pick a file using JFileChooser. It compiles fine, but no dialogue box opens up, and I can't figure out what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.File; 
import javax.swing.JFileChooser; 

public class Dummy {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); 
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/Users/AMDX12/Desktop"));
        fc.setDialogTitle("Choose File");
        fc.showOpenDialog(null); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It does show an "open file" dialog in my machine...

Comment: Could I be missing a built-in file? I transferred computers and a lot of my old code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: If that's the case, then you might want to reinstall your JDK. I tested on 1.8.0_111 and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you. I reinstalled everything (Eclipse IDE and the JDK) just to be sure and now it runs fine.